# Set variable from <input> value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I need to implement Google Analytics (Universal/analytics.js) on a 20-something part AJAX-based questionnaire. The questionnaire works something like a choose-your-own-adventure, whereas the follow-up questions are all determined by the preceding answers.

Each input has a name and an ID. I'm interested in pulling the value from this field and setting it as a global variable in a dataLayer. Everything has a unique ID and Name, which I've started collecting in a database.

Here's an example of the HTML:

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_2_Table1" class="CompSSRadio" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <td class="CompSSRadioLabel">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="CompSSRadioResponses">
                <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_2_1_48_1" class="CompSSRadioResponses" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_2_1_48_1_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$2$1_48_1" value="4" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_2_1_48_1_0"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Museo 500"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Museo 500"></SPAN>Test answer 1</SPAN></SPAN></label></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_2_1_48_1_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$2$1_48_1" value="5" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_2_1_48_1_1"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Museo 500"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14pt"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Museo 500"></SPAN>Test answer 2</SPAN></SPAN></label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Here is the "next" button:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnNext2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext2" src="../App_Themes/Images/Right.gif" onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('//forward.html');window.document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext').disabled=true;window.document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext2').disabled=true;__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnNext2','');" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

And here is a script which does something with the form info:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I don't know if I need to hook into that or anything, since that's what's submitting information. Obviously I'm clueless. I feel like this is a fairly simple task, it's just my lack of javascript knowledge preventing me from crafting the necessary script.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: give me an example about your result expectation , may help me to answer your question

Comment: Thanks! Maybe something like this?

<script>
dataLayer = [{
'question1': 'answer2',
</script>

Where answer2 would be populated by the script in question

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using radios to select one of multiple values, all radio elements must have the same name. For example, if you have:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" id="radio_male">
<label for="radio_male">Male</label>

<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" id="radio_female">
<label for="radio_female">Female</label>
```

You will only be able to select "Male" or "Female", but not both.
Taking that in consideration, the way to access the selected value, in Javascript, should be:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("sex");

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var el = elements[i];

    if ( el.checked ) {
        alert("Checked value: " + el.value);
        break; // Because only one radio from the group will be checked, there's no point in checking the rest of them, if there are more
    }
}
```

About Data Layer, I have no clue, but it sounds like you are having problems getting the values, if I'm understanding it well.

Comment: You've got it. I might not end up doing it with a datalayer, and end up using a ga(send command instead.

One caveat is that some fields are text entry boxes, though they have the same unique IDs. Would this be any different?

Comment: You mean `<input type="text" id="input_text_1" value="...">`? The way of accessing its value is `document.getElementById('input_text_1').value`. Remember that `id` is supposed to be unique (that's why you don't use a `for` cycle like I did in the answer). If you want to "group" multiple items, you should do something else (like adding a CSS class `<input class="class_name" ...>` and select them using `document.getElementsByClass('class_name');`, much like the example I gave you above as the answer).

Comment: Sorry, I meant `document.getElementsByClassName('class_name');`

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to jQuery, an even simpler method would be:

```
var dataObj = {};

// Get the name / value pair of the checked radio button
jQuery('input:checked').each(
    function() {
        dataObj[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    }  
);
```

etc.

There's several techniques you could use to move through the fields in order.  With a bit more context in the question (as in what the behavior is from one question to the next - can you get the next element ID from your ajax call, for example?), a more robust answer could get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, I'm in the process of collecting all answer IDs. With a list of these IDs and their corresponding question numbers, how can I use this jQuery script to define the questions?

I was thinking something like this: 

ga('send', {
'hitType' : 'pageview',
'page' : '{{QuestionNumber/AnswerNumber}}',
'title' : '{{Page Title Variable}}'
});
Where the values for page and title are set from the question number, answer selected, and question title, respectively.